# jQuery is not filtering/selecting on IE after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have the following code that works on Firefox and Chrome

```
$("#adicionarItem").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: $("#formAdicionaItem").attr("action"),
        data: $("#formAdicionaItem").serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            alert($("div#errors", response).size());
        }
    });
});
```

In IE the alert always returns zero. In Firefox/Chrome it returns 1 which is the expected value.
Does anyone know if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would happen if the response is somewhat malformed.
Make sure that all of the tags in the response are correctly closed.

Comment: thats not it. I validated the markup at w3c markup validator.

Comment: its the full page that is returning... it dosent fit well here.